Civimail traditional full links showing
Occasionally we use the Email Send/Schedule by Civimail (traditional) function when we're mailing members in a group of more than 50. As with all 'mass mailings, we're obliged to include tokens for Opt out, Unsubscribe as well as one that specifies the domain which is fine. The issue is that when the recipients receive the emails in their inbox, they do not see hyperlinked versions of Unsubscribe or Opt-out but instead they see the full detailed link which looks a bit unusual to them as they're this kind of thing u.462.92790.8a47af252733f095@em9694.organisation.org.uk
Does anyone else have this issue and if so how did you resolve it?
Thanks

You might have used the wrong token for Unsubscribe or Opt-out
